# Is there a way to add single nodes/edges in JSON format to networkx graph?

Tags: python, json, networkx

With `graph = nx.node_link_graph(json.loads("json_string"))` it is possible to load a graph that is represented in JSON format.
Now my problem is that I already have a networkx graph in my program and only want to add JSON formated components dynamically during runtime.
For example somewhere the string ' {"source": 1, "target": 2, "weight": 5.5} ' is created and should then result in a new edge between node 1 and 2.
What is the best way to realise this?

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way you can add the new edge to the graph `G` if you have a dict like this:

`d = {"source": 1, "target": 2, "weight": 5.5}` (you can convert it from string to dict with `dict(s)` or `json.loads(s)`) is:

`G.add_weighted_edges_from([(d['source'], d['target'], d['weight'])])`

Comment: `dict(string)` raises an error: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: Looks like your `string` is not a valid dict. Can you paste it in the comment?

Comment: Your example works well for that particular case, the problem is that was just an example and in reality I have a varying number of attributes after "source" and "target" and furthermore "weight" is not always one of those. Is there a more general way?

Comment: `dict("""{"source": 1, "target": 2, "weight": 5.5}""")` raises an error